# Locate function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-function

I have a PostgreSQL database with 37 schemas and > 500 functions. I'm trying to locate a specific function but am not seeing it when I manually browse the database tree in pgAdmin.

Is there a command in PostgreSQL to locate the schema that a specific function is in?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe querying  information_schema.routines might help?

Comment: Either query the catalogs, or use `pg_dump --schema-only <dbname>` and grep/edit the output.

Comment: `\df function_name` from inside [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  information_schema.routines to do this:

```
SELECT specific_schema,  specific_catalog, routine_schema, routine_catalog 
FROM  information_schema.routines
WHERE routine_name = 'X' AND routine_type = 'FUNCTION';
```